# Having difficulties using selenium module

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm still new to python and I was experimenting with selenium. It opens a Firefox browser when I use it directly from the Windows terminal. But when I change the directory to desktop and try to open the browser from there, it say the 'geckodriver' isn't in Path. I have the driver in path

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

And sometimes the browser opens but it closes immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs: [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/), you have to initiate driver, you can do this with hard coded location, example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service(executable_path="/path/to/geckodriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

then, to take an action on browser, you need to get a page, example:

```
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html")
```

Comment: Hey, the browser closes automatically after execution. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: follow this: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/